# Bean Binding in Spring java

Tags: java, spring

I have a set up like below

```
 SampleBean bean;
 Boolean threadRun = true;
     while(threadRun) {
     bean = context.getBean("sampleBean");
     threadRun = bean.getThreadRun();
 }
```

Assume `bean` object is singleton and is prone to changes from other threads. Here for every iteration the bean has to be obtained from the application context. Is there any way to do make the `bean` object to detect changes to it?

Comment: You can use the Observer pattern AKA listener. PropertyChangeListener for instance

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987476/java-propertychangelistener

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!