# Why does PeropertyChangeListener in Java not work following oracle's tutorials?

Tags: java, propertychangelistener

Why is this not working? I have implemented this by looking at the examples at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html#bound and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html
Even this post did not help me [Java PropertyChangeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987476/java-propertychangelistener) and others for that sake, not going to link all the posts I have looked through so what is it that I am doing wrong or have I misunderstood something about the Listener works? Here is my code:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private Integer age;

    private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("name", this.name, name);
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
        this.propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("address", this.address, address);
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
        this.propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("age", this.age, age);
    }

}
```

My Listener class:

```
public class PersonChangeListener implements PropertyChangeListener {

    public PersonChangeListener() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("test");
        String value = "old value: " + evt.getOldValue() + " New value: " + evt.getNewValue();
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

And my main entry:

```
public class ListenerTestMain {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.addPropertyChangeListener(new PersonChangeListener());
        person1.setName("Frank");
        person1.setAddress("Street 3");
        person1.setAge(26);

        Person person2 = new Person();
        person2.setName("Joe");
        person2.setAddress("Avenue Lane 3");
        person2.setAge(26);



        if (!person1.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(person2.getName())) {
            person1.setName(person2.getName());
        }

        if (!person1.getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase(person2.getAddress())) {
            person1.setAddress(person2.getAddress());
        }

        if (!person1.getAge().equals(person2.getAge())) {
            person1.setAge(person2.getAge());
        }

    }

}
```

So when I am setting the new values for `person1` in this case `name` and `address`I expect the `propertyChanged` method to be called in `PersonChangeListener` for each of them. But that does not happen, at least I am not getting anything outputted in my console.

Anyway is it because the `PropertyChangeListener` is only working for some specific java library like javafx or the likes? Do I have to implement a custom event trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the property then call the handler. At that point `this.name` (i.e. the `oldValue`) and `name` (i.e. the `newValue`) are equal, ergo the event won't fire.

Either call the handler before setting the value (I do not advise) or use another variable to hold the old value.

Comment: Hahaha Thanks @Hossein - Why the heck did I not notice that sorry, should have looked closer into the tutorials xD. They are even showing it by storing the old value into a local variable. Thanks a lot! It works now, feeling a bit stupid haha xD need some more coffee.

Comment: No worries @TheLearner. Happens to the best of us.