# How to make a variable in Java that is accessable by all classes and functions?

Tags: java

Say I have the boolean n that gets changed to true in classB. However, in classA, n is false until someone makes it true in classB.

How is this done?

I think it might involve a static variable but I'm not sure.

I tried typing public static boolean n = false; inside a class, and that did not work. Making a variable that way outside of any classes did not work either.

Comment: show us what you tried.

Comment: Make a class with boolean variable in  it. Make it instance as singleton and you can use it anywhere.

Comment: @SyedIbrahim: That is not true if they are not marked final.  Making a static variable is correct -- but it is also generally considered bad practice.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Do you make the static variable inside of a class, or outside of all classes?

Comment: Maybe you need property change listener:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987476/java-propertychangelistener

Comment: You cannot make anything outside of all classes.  You already have the right solution (for what you want to do, which may not be a good idea).  You will need to access it with the class, e.g. `MyClass.n`, of course.

Comment: @louiswasserman I did not try accessing it with the class like you said. I will try it now.

Comment: @louiswasserman that seems to have worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the right solution (for what you want to do, which may not be a good idea). You will need to access it with the class, e.g. MyClass.n, of course.